# Two versions of one model

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

This is a bit weird but I need to have two versions of the same model in node.js. I'm gonna try to do my best explaining.

I have to create two different acc types based on the fact if they're a job seeker or an employer. The fields are quite different and I cannot really change them.

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var plm = require('passport-local-mongoose');
var accountSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  username: String,
  accType: String,
  companyName: String,
  contactPersonFullName: String,
  email: String,
  companyWebsite: String,
  city: String,
  province: String,
  postalCode: String,
  phoneNumber: String,
  hiringRegion: String[], // TODO
  description: String,
  logo: String, //TODO
  workingWithEOESC: Boolean,
  industry: String,
});
accountSchema.plugin(plm);
module.exports = mongoose.model('account-employer', accountSchema);
```

This ^ is my employer account model. And this is my job seeker model:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var plm = require('passport-local-mongoose');
var accountSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  username: String,
  accType: String,
  city: String,
  province: String,
  postalCode: String,
  phone: String,
  ageGroup: String,
  education: String,
  lookingForWork: Boolean,
  employmentStatus: String,
  workingWithEOESC: Boolean,
  resume: String, //TODO
  mainWorkExp: String,
});
accountSchema.plugin(plm);
module.exports = mongoose.model('account-seeker', accountSchema);
```

I thought this is a good idea, but then I realized I need `one` account model, because of how `passport` works in Express. How can I make sure that different user types have different fields and info in the NoSQL db while keeping one account to log in and register? I might be making no sense now but I cannot see a way out of this situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var plm = require('passport-local-mongoose');
var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  accType: String,
  companyName: String,
  contactPersonFullName: String,
  email: String,
  companyWebsite: String,
  city: String,
  province: String,
  postalCode: String,
  hiringRegion: String[], // TODO
  description: String,
  logo: String, //TODO
  workingWithEOESC: Boolean,
  industry: String,
  phone: String,
  ageGroup: String,
  education: String,
  lookingForWork: Boolean,
  employmentStatus: String,
  resume: String, //TODO
  mainWorkExp: String,
  isEmployer: Boolean // added this one to distinguish between employer and employee
});
userSchema.plugin(plm);
module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

Why not combine them into one schema and add one more field to just check if this is an employee and employer.

Comment: That is an option. So during registration the rest would just be empty. And then I'd pick the ones I need like in SQL... Ok makes sense.

Comment: yes. its no-sql so each document can have different fields.